# Nexus shifter with Alfine hub

Tags: shimano, shifter, nexus

Is it ok to use a Nexus 8 speed grip shifter with an Alfine 8 speed hub?
The Alfine shifters seem to be all trigger shifters is that correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have tried this on 2 different Alfine 8 hubs. Been running it for a couple of years and it works great. 
Basically you can use the Nexus twist shift with the Alfine 8 hub and it works fine.

Answer (score 5):

The [Jtek bar end shifter](http://jtekengineering.com/barendshifter.php) claims to work with both Nexus and Alfine 8 speed hubs, so I don't see why other shifters wouldn't.

A comment on [this review](http://www.bikeradar.com/gear/category/components/hubs/product/review-shimano-alfine-disc-hub-31670) of the Alfine hub backs that up: "Apparently the Shimano Nexus Inter-8 twist shifter can be used with the Alfine hub if you want to avoid endless button-pushing."

Comment: nice one thanks for the info twisting I shall be. The twist grips are also a bit cheaper than the Alfine triggers too.